# Setting a Selected Option in a Template Using jQuery or Coffeescript

Tags: jquery, select, coffeescript

I have a coffeescript that creates dropdown list and select the list depend on returned value here is my coffeescript

```
var op=operator;
html = """
 <select _name="op">
      <option value="" #{'selected' if op == ''}>=</options>
      <option value="$ne" #{'selected' if op == '$ne'}>&ne;</options>
      <option value="$lt" #{'selected' if op == '$lt'}>&lt;</options>
      <option value="$lte" #{'selected' if op == '$lte'}>&le;</options>
      <option value="$gt" #{'selected' if op == '$gt'}>&gt;</options>
      <option value="$gte" #{'selected' if op == '$gte'}>&ge;</options>
    </select>
 """
  el = $(html)
```

the question is how to use this `#{'selected' if op == '$gte'}`  inside jquery
is there any plugin or library to do that in jquery ?
i tried outside the option but i want it inside each option to do that.

Comment: Don't use "var" in coffeescript. Where is the operator coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Consider manually setting the select option with javascript outside of your html template.

```
document.getElementById(op).setAttribute("selected", "true")
```

Or using jQuery

```
$("#" + op).attr("selected", "true")
```

Note that this would require you to add the operator as the id to each option element.